# Gridview onclick images display imageview as gallery view using viewpager

Tags: java, android

My apps display images as gridview and click on any image display gallery view allow to swipe left and right using viewpager. My code as below,

```
public class MemorialPhotoAlbumViewpager extends FragmentActivity {

static Activity MemorialPhotoAlbumViewpagerActivity;
int positionstate = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Intent intent = getIntent();
      String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("ArrayphotoAlbum");
      int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    setContentView(R.layout.photo_album_viewpager);

       // check the version of android

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

     ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(myStrings,position);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);




}


private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     private String[] ArrayphotoAlbumb;
     private int positionb;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(String[] myStrings, int position)
    {
        ArrayphotoAlbumb = myStrings;
        positionb = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return ArrayphotoAlbumb.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      Context context = MemorialPhotoAlbumViewpager.this;

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

      String test = ArrayphotoAlbumb[position];

      Bitmap bimage=  getBitmapFromURL(test);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bimage);



     ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

  }

  public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
      try {

          URL url = new URL(src);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.connect();
          InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
          Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

          return myBitmap;
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

          return null;
      }
  }
```

i can get the display out but the viewpager position always start with 0. how can i if i click on second image on the gridview and display it using viewpager allow to swipe to the left to display the first images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting a new activity for view pager, get the position of selected image from gridview and pass it to that activity. Then you can set selected image in view pager like,

```
pager.setCurrentItem(currentid); // here current id is the position of selected image.
```

Comment: u solved my problem. Thanks. Between i'm facing another problem when i try to swipe to left and right it like delay/hang a while only load the images. Any idea for that?

Comment: Are you using image caching? You have to effectively handle the bitmap in order to avoid that delay.

Comment: i'm just using this code

 `URL url = new URL(src);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.connect();
          InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
          Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);`

Comment: Have a look at this library- https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader Its an awsome library to cache images from web and effectively handle them.